# Install Windows 7 on bootcamp with broken DVD drive

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp

I'm upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 7 on 15 iMacs with Snow Leopard using bootcamp. Unfortunately on one of the iMacs the DVD drive seems to be broken. What are my options ? Can I use an USB stick ? And if yes, how ? An external drive (I have one from Apple). Thanks.

Comment: And will an iMac with a Bootcamp partition and no Windows on it allow me to boot from the USB ?

Comment: Yes, you can upgrade from windows xp to windows 7 using bootcamp option with USB drive. But think that you have to format the USB drive in FAT not in NTFS.

Comment: Can you please be more detailed ? Thanks.

Comment: A) You can't 'upgrade' from XP to Win 7 & b) there is a lot of hoop-jumping to get a SuperDrive machine to boot to USB… looking for links, will post answer...

Comment: Try this http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1680652 there is also mention that disconnecting the superdrive helps. I've never actually tried this, I bought a new 'fake' superdrive for £15 & wired it into the SATA.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Boot Camp to install Windows on your Mac, you’ll need to re-partition your drive. You’ll also need a USB drive at least 8 GB in size. The Boot Camp Assistant will copy the Windows installation files from an ISO file or physical disc to a USB drive. Windows will install itself on your Mac from this USB drive. The latest Windows drivers will also be downloaded from Apple and placed on this drive, and they’ll install automatically after you install Windows. After your Mac finishes creating a USB installation drive, you’ll see the Create a Partition screen. You can now divide your Mac’s system drive into two separate partitions — one for Mac OS X and one for Windows. Click the Install button and Boot Camp Assistant will resize your Mac OS X partition and create the new partition for Windows. Your Mac will then restart and boot the Windows installer from the USB drive. Go through the installer and install Windows on your Mac like you’d install it on any other PC. Select the partition labeled BOOTCAMP when you reach the Where do you want to install Windows? screen. Click the Format option to format the partition as NTFS, and then click Continue.

Comment: I know the procedure, I have already installed it on 5 of the 15 iMacs, but, as I wrote, 1 has broken DVD drive. I'm running Snow Leopard on a late 2009 iMac and the Bootcamp Assistant does not offer me the option to use an USB drive.

Comment: Does your iMac recognize your Flash Drive?

Comment: yes usb works properly

Comment: Would creating a bootable USB from ISO under Windows work after installing rEFIt on OS X ? Something like this http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/9136/...nal-dvd-drive/

Comment: I don't know but I would try it. If that doesn't work, you have your external HDD, you can take out HDD and put DVD drive in. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHcyidicolg , http://lifehacker.com/5463413/gut-an-old-usb-hdd-enclosure-to-make-an-external-dvd-drive